# dotenv-webpack use environment variable in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, dotenv

My `.env` is set up like this:

```
SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey123
```

My `webpack.config.js` is set up like this:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
...
proxy: {
 'api': {
   target: 'foo.bar'
   headers: {'api_token': process.env.SECRET_KEY}
  }
}
...
plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: '.env',
    }),
]

}
```

However when I run my app I get an error saying that my api token is `undefined`

I know dotenv is working properly, because within my application itself I can do `console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY)` and see my secret key, however it appears this does not expose my environment variables within my `webpack.config.js` file itself.

Is there a way to configure dotenv-webpack to allow the use of environment variables within the `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use variables from your .env file in the webpack.config.js directly, understand that it behaves just as any other javascript file while being run, so you need to use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package directly in the config file, not the dotenv-webpack plugin, which inserts the variables into your bundled code.

I.e, just `npm install dotenv` and add `require('dotenv').config()` to the top of your webpack.config file.

Comment: D'oh! I am stupid. Thanks for this. I will be able to sleep now.