# Trouble using env variables

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, dotenv

Upon making this simple that uses the Github API to filter users and repositories, I recently learnt that having information pertaining to the API, like API keys, IDs, etc. is bad practise. In my particular case, having the client_ID and the client_secret. I recently learnt about environmental variables and how they can be used with the dotenv package, but I am struggling on how to use it. Here is what I tried:

1. I have tried making a server.js file where I will store the environmental variables after putting them in an env file. I was successful at this, but I can't use them in the github.js file
2. I tried using requiring the **dotenv** package directly in my **github.js** file, but an error pops up saying my class (Github) is not defined.
3. I've tried importing and exporting the env variables from the **server.js** file to the **github.js** file, but my Github class cannot be accessed.

I'm I missing something or I'm I using these environmental variables all wrong?

Relevant code is below

github.js

```
    class Github {
       constructor() {
           this.client_ID = "1037a4472aafe; // Trying to hide this
           this.client_secret = "aaad41dd6b1cf2331"; // Trying to hide this
           this.repos_count = 5;
           this.repos_sort = "created: asc";
       }

       async getUser(user) {
           const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?client_id=${this.client_ID}&client_secret=${this.client_secret}`);
           const repoResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=${this.repos_count}&sort=${this.repos_sort}&client_id=${this.client_ID}&client_secret=${this.client_secret}`);


           const profileData = await profileResponse.json();
           const repoData = await repoResponse.json();

           return {
               profileData: profileData,
               repoData: repoData
           }
       }
   }
```

app.js

```
// Instantiate GITHUB class
const github = new Github;
// Instantiate UI class;
const ui = new UI;

// Search input
const searchUser = document.getElementById("searchUser");

//search input event listner
searchUser.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    // Get input text
    const userText = e.target.value;

    if (userText !== "") {
        // Make HTTP call
        github.getUser(userText)
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.profileData.message === "Not Found") {
                //show alert
                ui.showAlert("User not found", "alert alert-danger");
            }
            else {
                // Show the profile
                ui.showProfile(data.profileData);
                ui.showRepos(data.repoData);
                ui.logInfo(data.profileData);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // Clear the profile
        ui.clearProfile();
    }
});
```

.env

```
client_ID=1037a4472aafe
client_secret=aaad41dd6b1cf2331
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

require("dotenv").config();

const client_ID = process.env.client_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.client_secret;


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "src")));
app.get("*", (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.html"))
});

console.log(process.env)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of `bundler`? , if this is the case you should start looking how to use `env` variables with the `bundler`.

**Ex:** if you are using `webpack` you have to configure your variables on the `webpack.config`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441255/dotenv-webpack-use-environment-variable-in-webpack-config-js) is related to your issue but with webpack